# C# Deserialization of xml file returns "'There is an error in XML document (1, 2).'" error

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I'm trying to deserialize an xml response I get from a call.
I've used Visual Studios "Paste Special" function to prepare my program for how the file is gonna look, and the only change I've made to the result of this is changing a field from private to public, so that I can access it in my code. (This is done outside of the snippet of code, just want to clarify that I've not made any changes in the code snippet)

**The error**

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'There is an error in XML document (1, 2).'
Inner Exception
InvalidOperationException: <Envelope xmlns='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> was not expected.
```

**Start of my class**

```
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class Envelope
{

    private object headerField;

    private EnvelopeBody bodyField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public object Header
    {
        get
        {
            return this.headerField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.headerField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public EnvelopeBody Body
    {
        get
        {
            return this.bodyField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.bodyField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

**Start of my XML**

```
<SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
    <SOAP:Header/>
    <SOAP:Body xmlns:wsu='http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd' xmlns:urn='urn:oio:medarbejder:1.0.0' xmlns:urn1='urn:oio:sagdok:3.0.0'>
        <ns0:ListOutput xmlns:ns0='urn:oio:medarbejder:1.0.0'>
            <ns1:StandardRetur xmlns:ns1='urn:oio:sagdok:3.0.0'>
                <ns1:StatusKode>0</ns1:StatusKode>
            </ns1:StandardRetur>
            <ns0:LaesResultat>
                <ns1:MedarbejderRef xmlns:ns1='urn:oio:sagdok:3.0.0'>
                    <ns1:UUIDIdentifikator/>
                    <ns1:URNIdentifikator>URN:OIO:KMD:LPE:MEDARBEJDERNR:00000001</ns1:URNIdentifikator>
                </ns1:MedarbejderRef>
                <ns0:Registrering>
                    <ns0:AttributListe>
                        <ns0:Egenskaber>
                            <ns0:Persondata>
                                <ns0:Gyldighedsstart>1970-12-12</ns0:Gyldighedsstart>
                                <ns0:Gyldighedsstop>2099-01-01</ns0:Gyldighedsstop>
                                <ns0:CPR-nummer>1234567890</ns0:CPR-nummer>
                                <ns0:Efternavn>Doe</ns0:Efternavn>
                                <ns0:Fornavn>John</ns0:Fornavn>
                                <ns0:PersonaleIdentifikator>01</ns0:PersonaleIdentifikator>
                            </ns0:Persondata>
                            <ns0:Persondata>
                                <ns0:Gyldighedsstart>2099-01-01</ns0:Gyldighedsstart>
                                <ns0:Gyldighedsstop>9999-12-31</ns0:Gyldighedsstop>
                                <ns0:CPR-nummer>1234567890</ns0:CPR-nummer>
                                <ns0:Efternavn>Doe</ns0:Efternavn>
                                <ns0:Fornavn>John</ns0:Fornavn>
                                <ns0:PersonaleIdentifikator>01</ns0:PersonaleIdentifikator>
                            </ns0:Persondata>
                        </ns0:Egenskaber>
                    </ns0:AttributListe>
                    <ns0:RelationListe/>
                </ns0:Registrering>
            </ns0:LaesResultat>
            <ns0:LaesResultat>
                <ns1:MedarbejderRef xmlns:ns1='urn:oio:sagdok:3.0.0'>
                    <ns1:UUIDIdentifikator/>
                    <ns1:URNIdentifikator>URN:OIO:KMD:LPE:MEDARBEJDERNR:00000002</ns1:URNIdentifikator>
                </ns1:MedarbejderRef>
                <ns0:Registrering>
                    <ns0:AttributListe>
                        <ns0:Egenskaber>
                            <ns0:Persondata>
                                <ns0:Gyldighedsstart>1970-12-12</ns0:Gyldighedsstart>
                                <ns0:Gyldighedsstop>2099-01-01</ns0:Gyldighedsstop>
                                <ns0:CPR-nummer>0987654321</ns0:CPR-nummer>
                                <ns0:Efternavn>Doe</ns0:Efternavn>
                                <ns0:Fornavn>Jane</ns0:Fornavn>
                                <ns0:PersonaleIdentifikator>01</ns0:PersonaleIdentifikator>
                            </ns0:Persondata>
                        </ns0:Egenskaber>
                    </ns0:AttributListe>
                    <ns0:RelationListe/>
                </ns0:Registrering>
            </ns0:LaesResultat>
        </ns0:ListOutput>
    </SOAP:Body>
</SOAP:Envelope>
```

The only thing I could think of that might fix it, is adding an "ElementName" to

> [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute

But tried it, and it gave same error.

What am I missing ?

Comment: did you check the XML file in the XML validator? I doubt, your XML is not valid.

Comment: every XML has a closing tag (or call it node), in the snapshot, it appears, some closing nodes/tags are missing.

Comment: `Exception InvalidOperationException: was not expected.` -- looks like you've got an invisible character at the start. Open it in a hex editor, see what the first few characters are?

Comment: @canton7 Not sure why it removed the text there oO It's supposed to say "InvalidOperationException: <Envelope xmlns='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> was not expected." I'll update the question :)

Comment: My go-to trick for debugging XmlSerializer deserialization is to take your model and *serialize* it to XML. See how the output differs from the thing you're trying to deserialize, then tweak your model until they match. Then deserialization should work

Comment: @MuhammadBashir I've tried validating the xml and no errors were found. I'll update my question with all of the xml :)

Comment: @canton7 I'm not sure how I do that, but your comment made me look through all my elements and names and found that I had been trying to deserialize EnvelopeBody rather than Envelope.  So thanks! :D

Comment: Just create an `Envelope` object, then use `XmlSerializer.Serialize` on it to generate XML

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was because I was trying to deserialize my EnvelopeBody rather than the Envelope. Between the naming in the xml file and the naming in the autogenerated classes, I simply mixed the two of them up, because they were so similar.

**Deserialization should always start at the root element**